# How to reexport `*` from a module that uses `export =`

Tags: typescript

I have a module `m`:

```
export = {
    a: 3
}
```

And then in my `index.ts` I want to re-export everything that `m` is exporting, so I use:

```
export * from './m';
```

But it gives me an error:

> **Error:** TS2498:Module `D:/Projects/typescript/m` uses `export =` and cannot be used with `export *`.

How to re-export from a module that uses `export=` syntax? I have no control over the module with `export=` syntax.

Comment: Why do you need to export it with a "="? export const m = {a: 3}; is not enough?

Comment: I have no control over the module with export= syntax.

Comment: Have you tried `import m = require("./m"); export m;` ?

Comment: What worked for me: `export { default as m } from './m';`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use

```
import m = require("./m");
export {m};
```

or

```
import m = require("./m");
export default m;
```

Old style imports `export =`, `require()` aren't compatible with module exports.

Refer to [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

**UPDATE** for JSON file import
The following works using the `from` syntax, once you turn on the required tsconfig option. Available since 2.9.

```
import myObjectName from './path/to/file.json';
export { myObjectName };
```

Comment: how to export *, so we can use import {something} from 'module' instead of import {all} from 'module' and then cons something = all.something ??

Comment: You can also try:
```
import * as moduleA from "module-a";
export default moduleA;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are can not use es modules(`import`, `export`) for some reason, you can do it like this with `require`:

```
const reexported = require('./some/path')

Object.keys(scripts).forEach(key => {
  exports[key] = reexported[key] // exports is a special variable
})
```