# How to re-export types from 3rd party library in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am currently working on an SDK and would like to re-export types from a third-party library and expose them to developers. Typically, I achieved this using barrel exports inside the SDK module using those respective third-party types.

For example:

```
export * from '@foo-bar/feature';
```

Unfortunately, the third-party library I am working with performed `export = obj;` which prohibits me from doing barrel exports.

> Error: TS2498: ...  uses export = and cannot be used with export *.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892470/how-to-reexport-from-a-module-that-uses-export) which is similar, however I'd like to add the constraint that I am want users to be able to import the exported types directly using named imports, such as:

```
// I'd like this
import { MyTypeA, MyTypeB } from './abc';

// I don't want this
import { all } from './abc';
const MyTypaA = all.MyTypeA;
```

I got it to partially work using object destructuring, however, when forced to use the generated `d.ts` file in the transpiled source it didn't work for me as the types extracted would be `typeof` instead of the literal type.

Any ideas would be appreciated -- thank you.

Comment: There are other implications to using destructuring and re-exporting the destructured members. You are fundamentally changing the semantics of the module that you are re-exporting. Also, I think your whole approach is misguided. You should not be re-exporting third-party libraries. By doing so, you make it very difficult for end-users to resolve version conflicts and also make it harder for them to understand what they are consuming, where to find documentation for it, and where to file bugs for it. Just discard the practice all together.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Unfortunately I might need to re-export types in some fashion because I use the third-party types in my library as they're inter-related in terms of functionality. For example, creating an SDK on-top of Elasticsearch, I'd need to export some Elasticsearch type for the developer to use unless I force them to import Elasticsearch as well.

Comment: That's what dependencies are for. `package.json`: `{"dependencies": {"third-party-lib": "^x.y.z", "@types/third-party-lib": "x.y.z"}}`

Comment: Can you perform module augmentations on-top of dependencies though?

Comment: Yes. That's actually why module augmentation was added to the language. So that you could augment types from other packages without modifying them

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach though is that users need to willingly do two sets of imports: first from my SDK and then from the package. Thanks for your advice!