# how to re-export * from a module that uses export =

Tags: typescript

I want to re-export * from `typescript` which uses `export=`
this causes the error `TS2498: Module '"node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript"' uses 'export =' and cannot be used with 'export *'.`

I checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801887/12577650 but it suggest to use a symbol `m`, I want to `export *`

Comment: The error strongly suggests that typescript simply does not support this.

Comment: I expect it doesn't allow that because it's nonsense. What would it mean exactly?